# A-Level Normal Distribution Exam Question

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

When Ali competes in long jump competitions, the length of his jumps are normally distributed with mean 5.2m and standard deviation 0.7m.

Ali needs to jump 6m to qualify for the school team. What is the probability that he qualifies with one jump? What is the probability that, if allowed three jumps, that he qualifies for the team?

I was able to solve part 1 of the question (0.127 to 3sf) and, assuming that each jump is independent in part 2, I tried to use the binomial distribution, with X - B(3,0.127) and with the number of successes being 1, I got the answer of 0.290371149 (with 0.127 as p) or 0.2896389432 (with 0.1265489545 as p). However, the mark scheme says that the answer is 0.334, and I don't know where I have gone wrong.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you calcluated the probability that Ali makes *exactly one* jump over $6$m. It is possible that Ali cleared $6$m on two, or even all three, jumps. So you need to take those possibilities into account too.

The easiest way to do this: Ali fails to make the team if and only if he jumps less than $6$m on all three attempts. This occurs with probability $(1-0.127)^3$, so the probability that this doesn't happen (and hence Ali makes the team) is $$1-(1-0.127)^3\approx0.33$$

Comment: Thank you very much!